# How to debug loading shared library

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging

I have a multi-process program run on MIPS CPU with uclibc and it is compiled with gcc 4.5.3.
One of the process(it is name "tv") require to linked with one shared library(libtest.so) which is also written by me.  The "tv" process is written in C++ and libtest.so is in C.

I have also dump the elf header from libtest.so, it has both PIC and CPIC flag set, so I think the creation of the library is OK.

When I try to run the program, all the processes starts fine except the "tv" process.  There is no error message.  When I use ps to check it's status, it has become a zombie process.

I have tried the following

1. If I remove the libtest.so from linking process, and remove any reference to the libtest.so, the "tv" process can run without any issue.
2. If I remove any reference to the libtest.so BUT keep the libtest.so in the linking process, the "tv" process still does not run.
3. I have tried to use LD_DEBUG=all to debug, but it does not work in my board as there is no valid output.

So I am guess there is something went wrong when ld try to load the libtest.so when "tv" process is starting.  But I don't know how to debug?  How should I find out if the which part of libtest.so is causing the problem?

Any suggestion is welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting question. You seem to have a huge advantage in that you control libtest -- so you can try to reproduce the problem with a simple process (not tv), then slowly strip everything out of libtest until the problem disappears, then re-add until you can pinpoint the problem (binary search style). Unless the problem turns out to be reproducible *only* with tv and an unmodified libtest.so, in which case, good luck?

Comment: @mattn I have used strace and find out I am getting a SIGBUS.  Now I am going to try to find what is cause this. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @Cameron I have tried your suggestion and finally pin point the problem.  It is cause by mixing C and C++ code in libtest.so.  I still cannot figure out what is the exact reason, but at lease I have identified the problem area.  Thank you again. :)

Comment: Would you mind answering your own question with a summary of the tips and what you did? It might help other.s

Comment: @HugoFS Actually I still have not able to find the root cause of this problem.  I think what I do is a workaround. What I have done is the 3 steps that I have listed, and follow Cameron's advise to narrow down the problem area.  I will keep try to find out what is the root cause and if I do, I will try to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this isn't related to missing out on the extern C declaration for your API which are to be invoked as C functions.

Comment: I am sure it is not due to missing extern "C" declaration, because the linker won't link as the function name will get changed by the C++ compiler.

Comment: Your libtest.so is compiled with the C compiler so the function names will not be mangled. I'm wondering if when you compile your tv application how the C++ compiler will behave if your header file exporting the libtest.so API doesn't have the extern "C" declaration. [reference](http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html#c_from_cpp)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in load process. So write simplest application which loads your library and unloads it immediatelly and debug it.